# Error starting eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to start eclipse and I'm getting the following error. I am running Indigo on a windows7 box and using java version 1.6.0_24. Here is the error:

```
!SESSION 2011-07-04 02:27:06.256 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-07-04 02:27:07.496
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.load(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.getChannel(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.Locker_JavaNio.lock(Locker_JavaNio.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.lock(StorageManager.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: So after one year reinstall eclipse...

Comment: Look like an incompatibility between your JRE version and Windows version. You seem to be using Windows x86. Did you install JDK/JRE for Windows x86 (and thus not x64 or something)?

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would uninstall Java and then re-install. It's obvious that a file is missing or Eclipse is looking in the wrong place. Did you recently run a program that "optimizes" your computer? Or a registry cleaner? You could just try putting a file in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\ called nio.dll and see what happens. It could work and save you a bunch of time. Or you could just re-install Java. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the eclipse.ini file to include the vm option before -vmargs option as follows:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin\javaw.exe
```